How to reserve space for Sidebar to fix CLS (cumulative shift layout) Issue?

Live Preview for better analysis: https://premiumerblogger.blogspot.com/2024/07/vegas-pro-plugins-that-you-need-to-know.html
Hello there,
I've been trying to fix this CLS (Cumulative Layout Shift) issue for days but haven't been able to.
As you can see in the image, when I reload the page, the <main> element (Article content) loads first, centered using the justify-content: center; property. But when the sidebar (<aside> element) loads, it shifts the main content to the left, causing a CLS issue. I want to reserve space for the sidebar while keeping the main content's width the same and everything, including the sidebar, centered on the page.
I've tried many solutions, but they end up changing the styling on my homepage.
Is there anyone who is an expert in CSS and can join me on AnyDesk to share my screen? We can work together to fix this issue. Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.
The HTML code for  and  is too long however here's the CSS:
.maxC{margin-inline:auto;padding-inline:var(--contentPadding); max-width:var(--content-maxWidth)}    .mainB{gap:var(--contentSpace)} .mainB .blogB{width:calc(100% - (var(--sidebarWidth) + var(--contentSpace))); transition:width var(--tDuration), max-width var(--tDuration)} .mainB .blogB.item{max-width:var(--contentPost-maxWidth)} .mainB .blogB.static{max-width:var(--contentPage-maxWidth)} .mainB .sideB{gap:var(--contentSpace);width:var(--sidebarWidth); max-width:500px} .mainB .sideSticky{position:-webkit-sticky; position:sticky;top:calc(var(--headerHeight) + 10px)} .mainB .sideB .widget:not(:first-child){margin-top:var(--contentSpace)} .flex {
    display: flex;
}.flex.wrap {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
} .grow {
    flex-grow: 1;
} .flex.column {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.shrink {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

and here are the values for the variables: --contentPadding: 16px;      --content-maxWidth: 1300px; --contentSpace: 40px; --contentPost-maxWidth: 780px;     --sidebarWidth: 280px; --tDuration: .1s ease;
#CSS #HTML

Stack Overflow questions should include relevant code inside the question itself btw

Looks like the problem is that your  doesn't load until you have the content, so having the width declared doesn't reserve that space. Maybe put it inside a wrapper that is there on initial load, or ideally create it before having the content

I've added some code but the complete code can't be added as it's too long and that's why I asked to come via AnyDesk.

if you can't provide the relevant code in the question I suggest using Discord. Stack Overflow has a bunch of rules like that so that questions can be useful to others in the future. If you just want "help" rather than having a specific question I usually find Discord to be better suited

You can add .mainB::before while your aside is loading. A simple example:


setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('.mainB').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<aside class="sideB"></aside>'), 2000)
.mainB {
  --sidebarWidth: 80px;
  --contentSpace: 40px;
  min-height: 100px;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  width: min(400px,100%);
  margin: auto;
}

.blogB {
  width: calc(100% -(var(--sidebarWidth) + var(--contentSpace)));
  background-color: blue;
  flex: auto;
}

.sideB {
  gap: var(--contentSpace);
  width: var(--sidebarWidth);
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: none;
}

/* Here it is: */

.mainB:has(.blogB:only-child)::before {
  content: '';
  width: var(--sidebarWidth);
  flex: none;
}
<div class="mainB">
  <div class="blogB"></div>
</div>



